# Purpose of UFW Allow All Rules in FORWARD chain?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw, forwarding

What's the purpose of the allow all rules put into the FORWARD chain by UFW?  They're currently messing up the 5 ACCEPT rules I've put in place underneath.  Unless there's some specific valid reason for the allow all rules that I'm not aware of, I'd like to be able to block everything and only allow forwarding for the 5 rules that I've created.

Also, is there any easy way to delete the allow all rules?

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
2770   980990 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2770   980990 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 145     8700 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 145     8700 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 145     8700 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 145     8700 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       10.8.0.0/24          10.0.10.0/24        
   0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       10.8.0.0/24          10.0.11.0/24        
   0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       10.8.0.0/24          10.0.20.0/24        
   0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       10.8.0.0/24          10.0.21.0/24        
   0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       10.8.1.0/24          10.0.24.0/21
```